# why there is exclamation mark on wi fi. I am facing problem after upgrading to lollipop 5.0

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop

I have a Micromax AQ4501 mobile phone. I am getting an exclamation mark over the Wi-Fi icon. And I am unable to connect to Wi-Fi thereafter.

I have been facing this problem since a few days after I upgraded my phone to Lollipop 5.0. I tried many things like:

- switching off and then on,
- replacing SIM from slot 1 to slot 2,
- switching mobile data and Wi-Fi connection on and then off

but all in vain.

I called the Google call center but they were also unable to help me.

I am able to use internet through mobile internet, but unable to use Wi-Fi with this phone. My Wi-Fi is working fine on other gadgets like my laptop.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: When you upgraded, was it OTA stock or custom ROM? Have you contacted Micromax (or phone support)? If custom ROM, have you contacted the ROM developer?

Comment: Usually when there is an exclamation mark `!`, it is signifying that WiFi isn't fully connected. Meaning try open your browser, see if you have to login or sign in in order to finish connecting.

Answer (score 0):

in lollipop , '!' is shown usually when wifi is connected but unable to access internet for reasons like Sign-in into ISP webpage,etc .

i suggest u to turn off wifi router power supply and turn it on after 10 seconds,
this solved same problem for me

Comment: It shows this `!` even when I can access internet easily on my lollipop.

Comment: tried to connect different network ?

Comment: Same issue on others too. ROM is fine. Wifi works fine. It is this mark that looks odd, very odd.

Comment: does the mark appears at the time of connection or later after connected?

Comment: It does so at both times. Also, the mark is there on mobile data too which is working fine as well.

Comment: mark on mobile signal means wifi is off and mobile data is also off

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23337/discussion-between-firelord-and-pola-sai-ram).

Answer (score 0):

When I'm faced with this problem, I usually just edit the Wi-Fi network settings, by pressing the network name, and choosing "edit" (or "configure"). I then switch to" Static IP" instead of DHCP, and then manually input all the WiFi settings. This fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Did so long time ago, still the same issue. I left secondary DNS entry though, but it already defaults to 8.8.4.4.

Answer (score -2):

Try to forget all previous networks and then connect again to the current one. 
Hope this works.

Comment: What's the logic behind this? Not to mention, the issue persist in my device.

Comment: Yes, could you edit your question and explain a bit more.